# Stored procedure to insert into database table, missing semicolon error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

I was creating this stored procedure in MySQL for the first time and I stumbled upon this "semi colon missing" error and I'm stuck. Here's the code

```
    drop procedure if exists `Insert_User`;
    create procedure Insert_User(param1 varchar(20),param2 varchar(20))
    begin
        insert into login(username, password) values(param1, param2);
    end;
```

Comment: where are your delimiters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is within the delimiter. The query breaks on the ';' after your insert query. You can fix this by changing it. like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists `Insert_User`$$
create procedure Insert_User(param1 varchar(20),param2 varchar(20))
begin
    insert into login(username, password) values(param1, param2);
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this is what i have created so far...                                            DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_User(_Username VARCHAR(20),_Password VARCHAR(20),_Email VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT user_id FROM login WHERE username = _Username)    
            SELECT -1;     
      ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT user_id FROM login WHERE email = _Email;)     
            SELECT -2; 
      ELSE
            INSERT INTO login(username,password,email) VALUES(_Username, _Password, _Email);
                                  
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
     END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: What is it you are trying to do ?

Comment: i'm trying to check if username or email already exists by using stored procedure